# Running Apache NIFI with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-nifi

Hi I Have trying to run NIFI Apache on Docker using the DockerFile but i got error just like i attached in the Picture, is there any settings missing on the DockerFile?.

my Docker Compose File

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  nifi:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
      args:
        NIFI_VERSION: 1.8.0
        http_proxy: ${http_proxy}
        https_proxy: ${https_proxy}

    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nifi/conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
      - ./config/nifi/data:/home/nifi/data/data
      - ./config/nifi/script:/home/nifi/data/script
      - ./config/nifi/utils:/home/nifi/data/utils

  nifi-registry:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.registry
      args: 
        NIFI-REGISTRY-VERSION: 0.3.0
        http_proxy: ${http_proxy}
        https_proxy: ${https_proxy}

    ports:
      - "18080:18080"          
    volumes:
      - ./config/nifi-registry/conf:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-0.3.0/conf
      - ./config/nifi-registry/flow_storage:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-0.3.0/flow_storage
      - ./config/nifi-registry/database/:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-0.3.0/database
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NW2d.png)

Answer (score 1):

(sorry, can't comment yet, so I'm popping an answer)

Your log file says '/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-app.log' can't be open. Could it be a problem with your configuration file ?

Comment: that is the strange part, when i am using Ubuntu with the same setting all runs well, is there any different treatment on how Windows VM of Docker works against the Native Ubuntu?

Comment: Hmm, maybe is it something with volumes. Could you try:

`docker run --name nifi \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -d \
  apache/nifi:latest

Comment: docker run -v ./config/nifi/conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf --name nifi  -p 8080:8080 -d  apache/nifi:latest ls -la /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf

to make sure everything is there (I did not try the command) ?

Comment: yes i think it is also about the volume, is i deleted the line for the volume all runs well.. weird is it?, and i have not test out the command you are suggesting, since i am away from my machine that hosted this Docker